# How do you determine which X displays exist?

Tags: x11, multiple-monitors

I am on a Windows machine running cygwin and X, with three monitors.  When I ssh -Y to a remote machine, DISPLAY is set to something like localhost:15.0.  Is there a way to determine what other values can be used to point back to my local machine?

It seems that I should be able to do things like

```
DISPLAY=localhost:15.2 xeyes
```

to have the program appear on the second monitor.  However, so far, nothing except the default value has worked.  I've only tried localhost:15.1, localhost:15.2 and localhost:15.3, but I'm out of ideas as to what else I can try.

If there is a way to control the monitor other than DISPLAY, I'm happy to use that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think cygwin X supports screennumber in the display name for monitor-mapping. However, all X programs take a `-geometry` argument that you can use to set the initial window position. It’s documented in the “Geometry Specifications” section of the [X(7) manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/7/x). The X display is virtually a big rectangle enclosing all the monitors. If the top-left corner of monitor two is (1200, 0) in X coordinates, you can get xeyes to the top-left corner of monitor two by running `xeyes -geometry +1200+0`. If nothing shows up—maybe that coordinate is off-screen—try looking at the coordinates of an existing window by running `xwininfo` from a terminal and then clicking on the existing X window.

Comment: This isn't really the answer that I was hoping for, but wininfo is useful.